# how to skip a stage in jenkinsfile pipeline for certain agent names or labels?

Tags: jenkins, label, jenkins-pipeline

I have some build nodes in Jenkins with different labels, some of them being common:

```
#node name: labels
m_node1: m u16
m_node2: m u16
p_node1: p u16
p_node2: p u16
```

In my Jenkinsfile pipeline i have following snippet:

```
agent { node { label 'u16' } }
stage('parallel stuff') {
    parallel {
        stage('Stuff not for p') {
            steps {
                echo "My node name is ${env.NODE_NAME}"
                echo "My node labels are ${env.NODE_LABELS}"
                sh './should_not_run_on_p'
            }
        }
        // ... other stages 
    }
}
```

As the name indicates, i want

```
Stuff not for p
```

to run only if m_node1 or m_node2 is the current build node. If the stage lands on either p_node1 or p_node2, the stage should be skipped. For this i want to be able to say: "run if label 'p' not in NODE_LABELS", or "run if node name not like 'p_*'".  I tried following syntax based on the [jenkins pipeline when documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when):

```
when { not { ${env.NODE_NAME} "p_**" } }
```

This fails with following error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 158: Expected a when condition @ line 158, column 34.
                       when { not { ${env.NODE_NAME} "p_**" } }
                                ^
1 error
```

Following syntax is not working either:

```
when { not { environment name: 'NODE_NAME', value: 'p_*' } }
```

How do i best solve my problem ?

Comment: i solved it using [this page](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/01/19/converting-conditional-to-pipeline/) 

    when { not { expression { return env.NODE_NAME ==~ /(?i)p_.*/ }}}

Answer (score 0):

You can define specific agents for specific stages with the declarative pipelines that you already are using:

```
pipeline{
    agent none
    stage('parallel stuff') {
        parallel {
            stage('Stuff not for p') {
                agent {label 'm_node1 && m_node2'}
                steps {
                    // steps
                }
            }
           // ... other stages 
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: this suggestion assumes my list of nodes for 'm' and 'p' is fixed, which is not. Essentially, i dont want to maintain the node list in the Jenkinsfile, but rather use an expression that is going to work regardless of how many nodes have these labels.